# RE: Substitution using group

Tags: python, regex

I have provided the code and it's output below. I fail to understand how this substitution occurred. If you can explain step by step, it will be helpful.

```
import re
text = 'section{First} section{second}'
p = re.compile('section{([^}]*)}')
print 'before substitution: ', text
print 'after substitution: ', p.sub(r'subsection{\1}', text)
```

#### Output

```
before substitution:  section{First} section{second}
after substitution:  subsection{First} subsection{second}
```

Comment: essentially with regexes, groups of parentheses refer to groups, that you could then call to get the string representation of that group.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern `section{([^}]*)}` matched `section{First}`. In particular the parentheses indicate a capturing group: `[^}]*` matched `First` and this string was captured allowing it to be used later. Specifically it can be referred to in the replacement as `\1`. In string formatting terms, `section{First}` was replaced with `'subsection{%s}' % 'First'` which is `subsection{First}`. The section with `Second` is the same.